# Sending an email from scala - Authentication failed exception

Tags: scala, smtp

I am trying to send an email(gmail) from scala. Here is what I have so far-

```
import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._

// Get the user's message
var bodyText = "Hello World!"


// Set up the mail object
val props = System.getProperties
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user","user");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");

val session = Session.getInstance(props)
val message = new MimeMessage(session)

// Set the from, to, subject, body text
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com"))
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "myemail@gmail.com")
message.setSubject("First email")
message.setText(bodyText)

// And send it
Transport.send(message)
```

The error that I am getting is just

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

I understand that I may need to provide a password somewhere but I am following the tutorial http://langref.org/scala/networking/smtp/send-an-email and they don't require password.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#smtpauth, you should use `Transport.send(message, user, password)`